# Access js object globally in angular 6 components html

Tags: javascript, angular, angular6

I'm using Angular 6. I have somefile.js file with content:

```
SomeObject = {
    value1: "Some value",
    value2: "Some value2"
}
```

I have multiple components and I would like to access these values of this file/object in any of my components html.

For example in my components .html files I would like to access this file like:

```
<div>
 {{ SomeObject.value1 }}
</div>
```

How could I achieve something like this?

Comment: You mean AngularJS 1.6 or Angular 6?

Comment: I mean Angular 6

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your template can only see what is made public on the component. This means you need to create a public field on your component and assign your object to that field.

```js
import { SomeObject } from './path/to/some/object';

@Component({
// ...
})
export class FooComponent {
    SomeObject = SomeObject;
}
```

If you need the object in many places, you could define a decorator which does this for you.

Define the decorator:

```js
import { SomeObject } from './path/to/some/object';

export function SomeObjectDecorator(): Function {
    return (constructor: Function) => {
        constructor.prototype.SomeObject = SomeObject;
    }
}
```

Apply it to the component

```js
import { SomeObjectDecorator } from './path/to/some/object/decorator';

@Component({
// ...
})
@SomeObjectDecorator()
export class FooComponent {
}
```